# MessageBox changes something seemingly unrelated

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, user-controls

Here's my setup: I have a TabControl with numerous tabs, and on the last tab, I have a UserControl that is added to a TabPage.  This UserControl has a `VisibleChanged` event that is supposed to check if it is visible, and if it is displays certain information using `CustomCommand()`.

```
void MyUserControl_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("");
            UserControl us = sender as UserControl;
            if (us.Visible)
            {
                CustomCommand();
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("");
        }
```

Here is the problem: this code as-is will incorrectly think the UserControl is visible when it is not, and the `CustomCommand()` will run when it's not supposed to.  When the commented-out `MessageBox` function is un-commented in either spot, the UserControl is correctly seen as not visible until, of course, the TabPage is selected.  Does anyone have any idea why this would be?

Comment: How do you know it's not visible?  Is CustomCommand a long operation?

Comment: "Note that even if Visible is set to true, the control might not be visible to the user if it is obscured behind other controls." from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible(v=vs.110).aspx). It Does not quite explain, why it works with the message box, but it may explain why visible is true, even if the control is not displayed (ie. another tab may be displaying while the Visible property of your usercontrol is changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting it on a TabPage doesn't explain this problem.  There must be other layout events involved that make the control actually visible later.  The MessageBox.Show() call provides the time machine to get the Visible property checked with a delay.

The standard technique to get code to run later, the way MessageBox does, is by using the Control.BeginInvoke() method.   The delegate target runs when all events have been fired and processed and the UI thread goes idle again.  Like this:

```
void MyUserControl_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl us = sender as UserControl;
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        if (us.Visible)
        {
            CustomCommand();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but there is a strange, and afaik undocumented, **asymmetrical** behaviour with the `Visible_Changed` event:

- It does get raised whenever the Visible property of the control changes, **either** to true or to false.
- It also get raised whenever the Parent's Visible property changes to true and **only to true**!
- I could not raise the event by hiding the Control by another control, or for that matter by the `MessageBox`, though.

I don't know how your application works, so I could not reproduce. But I did notice that indeed, when changing tabs the `Visible_Changed` event of a Control on the TabPage does get raised, whenever the page is **selected** (but not when it is unselected.) I didn't know either.

You can try to catch the other direction by either going for the `SelectionIndexChanged` or by hooking into the `VisibleChanged` event of the TabPage. This is not visible in the IDE, but it does work both ways:

```
tabPagexyz2.VisibleChanged += tabPagexyz_VisibleChanged;

void tabPage2_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // do something
}
```

I saw wild guesses about UI race conditions being behind it, which I doubt. This would at least explain why a `MessageBox` would habe an influence. If you want to test, you could replace it with one the evil `Applictaion.DoEvents`.